# How to Index Nested Arrays in Javascript Properly?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var initialPos = [];
var totalNum = 5;
var dt = 1;
for (var i = 1; i <= totalNum; i++) 
{initialPos.push([i*100*Math.random(),i*100*Math.random()])}
var vx = 5;
var vy = 5;
var newPos = [];
var x_Pos;
var y_Pos;
for (var j = 0; j <= totalNum - 1; j++) {
  x_Pos = initialPos[j][0] + vx*dt;
  y_Pos = initialPos[j][1] + vy*dt;
  newPos.push([x_Pos,y_Pos])
  initialPos = newPos;
};
console.log(initialPos);
```

initialPos is an array of ordered pairs. I am trying to create another array called newPos and push some modified elements from initialPos to it, however I keep getting the error that the property of 0 of undefined cannot be read. Any suggestions on to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is `initialPos` defined...? Per Stack Overflow's guidelines, please provide only a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Forget indexes completely and use [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and in your case, possibly [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: There are too many undefined variables in your code so we can't possibly test and know what's wrong: what is `initalPos`? What is `vx`, `vy`, `dt`?

Comment: My apologies, I've added more of the code where these variables are defined

Comment: in your example `totalNum` and `dt` are still undefined

Comment: sorry, just fixed it

Comment: your loop for pushing values to initialPos starts with `1` index so you have undefined at `0` index and which produces the error,

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in this line `initialPos = newPos;`

You are assigning `initialPos` to `newPos`.
The first time you go through the loop newPos looks something like this `[ 27.07844010497107, 137.90462488567533 ];` and you are reassigning `initialPos` to this value.

The second time you go through the loop when `j === 1`, `initialPos[1]` is undefined as you assigned it to newPos that has a length of 1.

I am not sure what you want to do exactly, but isn't it what you need?

```js
var initialPos = [];
var totalNum = 5;
var dt = 1;
for (var i = 1; i <= totalNum; i++) 
{initialPos.push([i*100*Math.random(),i*100*Math.random()])}
var vx = 5;
var vy = 5;

console.log(initialPos);
for (var j = 0; j <= totalNum - 1; j++) {
  initialPos[j][0] = initialPos[j][0] + vx*dt;
  initialPos[j][1] = initialPos[j][1] + vy*dt;
};

console.log(initialPos);
```

As a side note, I suggest you look at immutability. Here is one [article](https://wecodetheweb.com/2016/02/12/immutable-javascript-using-es6-and-beyond/) for instance. It would prevent such bugs.